# Laravel5.4 with VUE can show the components

Tags: javascript, php

```
</body>
  <div id="app">
    <example></example>
  </div>
  <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

i got this error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLN9n.png)

here is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  }
}
```

here is my welcome.blade.php just changed a little .

my , app.js, webpack.mix.js,  and the component , i don't change them anymore .  on picture, there files can see this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phYOf.png)

Comment: The error screen shot is nice, but if you can copy/paste the error in it helps with indexing on the site and people are more likely be able to help.

Comment: sorry ,  but when I  npm run dev ( or watch  ) it,   i just got the message 'build successfully  ' but no error  . tips: i use laravel-mix now .  is my webpack settings wrong? i have no ideas